# 500 Internal Server Error for *.html and *.htm files

Tags: redirects, html

I look after the website airandmore.at, it is a wordpess site.

Now I ran into the problem that *.html and *.htm requests don´t work, for example do I get a "500 Internal Server Error" in case of https://airandmore.at/test.html

I disabled Yoast plugin (where I configured some redirects) and also renamed .htaccess. Problem still there.

In my eyes there should be a 404 in case this file is not available on the server or I should have the possibility to redirect certain (legacy) urls with *.html.

Any idea what could be the reason for the 500 error message in this case or how/where this could be changed?

Comment: A "500 Internal Server Error" is a very generic "something went wrong" error.   There is no way to solve this without getting more information from your `error_log` file.  Your log file should tell you which script is generating the error and what the underlying cause of the error is.

Answer (score 1):

It is commonplace for webservers servicing WordPress to check if a file exists, and if not pass the URL to WordPress to make sense of. This is typically done in the server config or .htaccess.

If this is the case, then the non existence of the file won't lead to an 404 error, it will be passed to WP, which appears to be having an issue handling the nonexistent URL and throwing up a 500 server error.